# Modify CSS class contents only if it is situated under certain other class?

Tags: css

I have a particular CSS class that behaves OK in my layout but fails to do so if it is located under bootstrap's accordion class. After some adjustments it works ok within the accordion but then it breaks its appearance in other places.

How it is best to define in CSS the following:

- Initially define class A
- If class A is under class B, apply following modifications to class A ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D They've described the *opposite* of a 'parent selector'. `If A under B, modify A`, not `if A under B, modify B`.

Comment: good point...deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've described a fundamental part of CSS, child & descendant selectors.

You can use the descendant selector  `parent descendant`, or the child selector `parent > child`, to change how an element looks / behaves when nested inside another element.

More Info:

- [Getting started with CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships).
- [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```css
.A {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  
  background-color: red;
}

.B {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.B .A {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.B > .A {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="A"></div>

<div class="B">
  <div class="C">
    <div class="A"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="B">
  <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```